# Smoke is gone from fire, only flames displayed

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

For some reason I can't figure out how to get the smoke to display. It was working before I made the resolution so high, something else must have changed. Please help!

[image]

[image: enter image de[![enter image description here]scription here][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoXLs.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoXLs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plTTs.png)

Comment: What are the sim settings? Please add images showing the settings for the domain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just added the sim settings and image of the render